# Does meta og:image actually load in background?

Tags: html, image, meta

I was curious if meta og:images actually load on the page in the background and slows down pagespeed.

I use Pinterest, and I try to make sure all 'pinnable' image weights are very low. The meta og:image weight is very high, as it is mostly for sharing on Facebook (Pinterest doesn't pick up the meta og:image anymore).

It doesn't make sense for me to have the very high weight AND very low weight image IF the meta og:image actually loads on the page in the background. That would bring the page speed down.

IF it DOES NOT load in the background, then I would keep it because - hey, why not have a really good display image on Facebook (and other sites that pick up the meta og:image)?

So, do meta og:images actually load on the page in the background and slows down pagespeed?

Answer (score 4):

No it is not loaded by browsers.

Comment: Indeed it doesn't, and you can always check these kind of issues with the network analyzer of your browser debugger; just check if any HTTP request is made to the image.